# how to get a single tab instead of multiple tabs on a button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My page contains 3 buttons New, Login, SignUp, and when I click New, I am getting form with two tabs, for New, Login and SignUp Buttons. But, I want, Login tab alone with page when I click the Login Button. And, SignUp tab alone with page, when I click on SignUp button. 
Hope, some wil sureply help me... I am completely new to this .....
Here is my code...
Thanks in advance

Here is my code...

New Page code:

Login

SignUp

Login

SignUp

```
<%= f.label :content %><br />





<%= f.text_field :content %>
```

```
<%= f.label :user_id %><br />




<%= f.number_field :user_id %>
```

```
<%= f.submit %>
```

-->

```
<div class="modal-footer">




    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>




    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>




</div>
```

Index code:

New Micropost

Login

SignUp

Comment: Unable to understand full code here. Are you trying to build 'Login/Sign Up' page?

Comment: Infact, I got a page with 2 tabs namely Login and signup when I click on "new" button. But, I want to display the page with Login tab when I click on Login button. and page with Signup tab when I click on sig up button.

Comment: Is this your full code? I guess your are missing form tag like 'form_for' or 'form_tag' here.

Comment: <%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>



<ul class="nav nav-tabs">

Comment: <li><a href="#new" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="#new1" data-toggle="tab">SignUp</a></li></ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="new">Login</div>
<div class="tab-pane " id="new1">SignUp</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :content %><br />
<%= f.text_field :content %></div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :user_id %><br />
<%= f.number_field :user_id %></div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></div>
<% end %>

Answer (score 0):

As far I got you, I think you need to do as below:

```
# index.html    
<%= form_for(MicroPost.new) do |f| %>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#new" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#new1" data-toggle="tab">SignUp</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="new">Login</div>
    <div class="tab-pane " id="new1">SignUp</div>
    <div class="field"> 
      <%= f.label :content %><br /> 
      <%= f.text_field :content %>
    </div> 
    <div class="field"> 
      <%= f.label :user_id %><br /> 
      <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
    </div> 
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is working for me.
Hope this would help.